# Best Method Of Using Bootstrap Navbar in ASP Web Application With Master Page

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ASP web Application that is Using Bootstrap. I want to use the Navbar componet from my master page to navigate my selection:

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I obviously want the best performance within my web application and don't want all my code slapped on one page because it would be mostly a data driven application which could prove tedious to load and I want to keep Page refresh and requests at a minimum. Would I use iFrames, Containers or any similar web based technology to navigate through my web application to achieve the optimal performance? The client's I am catering for would not have the best web connectivity but still need the bang for their buck so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to do is create a sql table that u will use for HTML injections to your page. So basically depending on a decision or selection you can populate the design of you page accordingly.